# Applying ARMAX model from r output

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I'm trying to apply R output to generate a scenario using external data, I'm not sure how exactly to use the coefficients in each from the R output.

I have an ARMAX(1, 1) model

- Coefficient of AR1: $A$
- Coefficient of MA1: $M$
- Intercept = $k$
- Coefficient of external regressors: $B_1$, $B_2$
- External regressors: $X_1$, $X_2$
- Y actual = $Y_a$
- Y predicted = $Y_p$

The formula I'm using is $Y_p = k + A*(Y_a(t-1)-k) - M*(Y_a(t-1) - Y_p(t-1)) + B_1*(X_1(t) - X_1(t-1)) + B_2*(X_2(t) - X_2(t-1))$

Is there anything wrong with the formula I'm using?
I'm asking because of two things, one is that while AIC is much better for this model, the sum of squared errors is actually higher than if I just used AR(1) model; another thing is that when I adjust the AR term, the sum of squared residuals gets reduced, but I thought the model is supposed to minimize the sum of squared residuals for each of the terms?

I'm using the same data set for generating the model and to fit the model, I need to test  to see how much improvement this model offers compared to simpler models. I'm doing the fitting in Excel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if additional information is needed to answer this please ask.

This is my R output

```
ARMA11R2R30


Call:
arima(x = YieldReOLD[, 5], order = c(1, 0, 1), xreg = cbind(YieldReOLD[, 2], 
    YieldReOLD[, 4]))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1  intercept  cbind(YieldReOLD[, 2], YieldReOLD[, 4])1
      0.9872  -0.1970    -6.2862                                   -0.1867
s.e.  0.0072   0.0489     0.3743                                    0.0566

      cbind(YieldReOLD[, 2], YieldReOLD[, 4])2
                                       -0.3999
s.e.                                    0.1140
```

Comment: Please give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I recommend that you read `?predict.Arima` - note that you need to feed *prediction* external variables into the `newxreg` parameter.

Comment: I have used predict.Arima before, and it doesn't seem to match the data that I used to create the model. I guess what I'm asking is more or less what is the formula used in the predict.Arima function.

Comment: Please read the help file for `arima`. It does not fit an ARMAX model. It fits a regression model with ARIMA errors.

Comment: Although this question is couched in terms of R, I believe it may be appropriate for CV because there are several questions about the nature of these models, AIC vs SSE, how to interpret coefficients, etc, that make it a better fit here than SO.

Comment: Wow I should have noticed that... That would make it pointless to compare it to an AR model

Comment: Sorry I'm new here, what is CV?